# How do I center the carousel control buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I go about adjusting the carousel control buttons to the centre on a sliding image `div` tag? Its only liking being "floated" to the left, except when I take the `float:left` CSS attribute, they go vertical instead of horizontal - what am I doing wrong here?

```css
.main-carousel-indicators {
    align-content: center!important;
    justify-content: center!important;
}
.main-carousel-indicators li {
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    display: block!important;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #219cdd!important;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    float: left;
}
.main-carousel-indicators .active {
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #0D0155!important;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="simple-carousel">
         <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic-main" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-duration="1000">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators main-carousel-indicators">
               <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
               <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
               <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
               <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
            </ol>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My propose is to use `line-block` instead of `block` for children elements, and `text-align:center` for parent:

```css
.main-carousel-indicators {
    align-content: center!important;
    justify-content: center!important;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-carousel-indicators li {
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #219cdd!important;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.main-carousel-indicators .active {
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    background-color: #0D0155!important;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="simple-carousel">
         <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic-main" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-duration="1000">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators main-carousel-indicators">
               <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
               <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
               <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
               <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
            </ol>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my computer from being thrown against the wall repeatedly. Answers has been market up.